# Conditional execution (IF, ELSE)  NOT WORKING

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, conditional-operator

I want to write a batch script statement where:
FINDSTR has to check for a string AND IF found then just print out FAILED and end the program
IF NOT FOUND then go check/look for another string AND IF FOUND then print out SUCCEEDED and close the program, IF NOT FOUND then print out the error message again. 
Any ideas?

Here is what I did:

```
ECHO Checking the log file for errors...
FINDSTR /C:"Open failed" some_Log.txt && (ECHO Deployment FAILED. 
cscript //nologo success_mail.vbs 
pause) || FINDSTR "RC (return code) = 0" && (ECHO Deployment was successful.
cscript //nologo fail_mail.vbs
pause)
```

I don't know why it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what i my latest one looks like:

```
  ECHO Checking the log file for errors...
    FINDSTR /C:"Open failed" some_Log.txt some_Log.txt && (
     ECHO Deployment FAILED. 
     cscript //nologo fail_mail.vbs 
     GOTO offshore ) || (
      FINDSTR /C:"RC (return code) = 0" some_Log.txt && (
        ECHO Deployment was successful.
        cscript //nologo success_mail.vbs 
        GOTO offshore)
      )
```

And, it is not working. Do you see any errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows batch or some other batch?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post some code that you've tried already

Comment: this stupid SO is not letting me answer my own stuff. it has way too many rules. doesn't make sense. If i put what i have right now to this comment area, you will not like the mess, honestly.

Comment: Edit your question to include the new information (there is a link under the tags).  Abusing SO is unlikely to encourage others to help you.

Comment: @Duper - you can edit your original question if necessary; you shouldn't be putting code in the comments or answering your own question unless you have solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, everyone. Sorry, if I offended anyone, but, gotta face it, SO has way too many rules and etc. I like the site, but sometimes it gets to you. BTW, just edited my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of potential problems.

- Your `%workDir%` or `%filenm%` could contain spaces or special characters. To be safe you should enclose them in quotes if you haven't already done so in the values.
- You must be careful when using both `&&` and `||` operators. If the command(s) after the `&&` fail, then it can cause the script to fall into the `||` section, even though the original command before the `&&` succeeded. I'm worried about your CSCRIPT command to send mail. Even if it succeeds today, perhaps it could fail in the future and your logic could be impacted.
- I'm guessing that the 2nd search string is supposed to be a phrase and not 5 different searches. Remember that search strings are delimited by space unless the /C option is used.
- Your 2nd FINDSTR is hanging because you have neglected to provide a file as input, so it is waiting for data on stdin.

I would structure your code like so

```
ECHO Checking the log file for errors...
set "file=%workDir%\%filenm%_DEV_Log.txt"
set "search1=Error: Open failed because: No such file or directory"
set "search2=RC (return code) = 0"
set "err="
FINDSTR /C:"%search1%" "%file%" && (set err=1) || (
  FINDSTR /C:"%search2%" "%file%" || set err=1
)
if defined err (
  ECHO Deployment FAILED.
  cscript //nologo success_mail.vbs "%filenm%_ddl_DEV.sql" "%file%"
  pause
) else (
  ECHO Deployment was successful.
  cscript //nologo fail_mail.vbs "%filenm%_ddl_DEV.sql" "%file%"
  pause
)
```

Comment: When I ran this, it printed out bunch of FINDSTR: Cannot open &&, FINDSTR: Cannot open err=1 and etc. Thanks, @dbenham

Comment: @duper - Sorry, I was missing a `"` in the very first SET statement. It has been fixed.

Comment: i am not sure what is going on with it, but, it is setting "err" to 1 even if it didn't fail. And keeps generating the first echo line followed by the first search1 line on to the cmd screen. I checked the log file, and it should have said "successful." Don't know what is going on.

Comment: thanks. Sorry, i think that was a mistake on my part. I think it is working. If anything else pops up, I'll uptade the post.